# Why does MYSQL set next-key locking when the statement is a multi-column unique key combination?

Tags: mysql, innodb

In the following queries we can see that when there is an OR statement(Senario 2) for the unique key in the where clause the locking of the next-key occurs, why this happens?

I have a multi column unique key on column `c1` and `c2`, and based on the MYSQL documentation, Gap locking is not needed for statements that lock rows using a unique index to search for a unique row.

```
DROP TABLE `t`;

CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `c1` int,
  `c2` int,
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_key_1` (`c1`, `c2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


insert into t (c1,c2) values (1,1);
insert into t (c1,c2) values (1,2);



-- Senario 1
start transaction;

select * from t where c1=1 and c2=2 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;

SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME, INDEX_NAME, LOCK_DATA
FROM
    performance_schema.data_locks
WHERE
    OBJECT_NAME = 't'
        AND INDEX_NAME = 'unique_key_1'
        AND LOCK_DATA = 'supremum pseudo-record';

commit;


-- Senario 2
start transaction;

select * from t where c1=1 and (c2=1 or c2=2) LOCK IN SHARE MODE;

SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME, INDEX_NAME, LOCK_DATA
FROM
    performance_schema.data_locks
WHERE
    OBJECT_NAME = 't'
        AND INDEX_NAME = 'unique_key_1'
        AND LOCK_DATA = 'supremum pseudo-record';

commit;
```

Comment: `and c2 in (c2= 1 or c2 =2)` -- the `IN(..)` becomes `IN(0,1)` if c2=2 or `IN(1,0)` c2=1 or `IN(0)` for all other cases.  I don't think that is what you expected.

Comment: @RickJames I fixed it, at first I had it with the in statement and then I changed it using the or statement, that's why I made the mistake, both the in and the or statement give the same result in scenario 2.

Comment: Now, let's see `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for both queries. I am not sure to point the finger at `OR` or at discuss why "gap locking" is sometimes used when it is _may_ not be necessary.